# Navigating large C# code files in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, large-files

I have some controllers in an MVC project that are a couple of KLOCs and contain more than 10 methods. I'm getting sick of scrolling to find these methods and I don't like expanding and collapsing regions all the time. I've written the method names at the top of the controller to keep track of where stuff is and separated the methods with horizontal lines so I can easily see where one method starts and another ends when scrolling through rapidly. I have some extra visual queues from breakpoints in the scrollbar if they are set. What I'd really like is to be able to write a method name at the top of my code file and by clicking on it, jump to that part in the code. Does this exist? If not, is there there a tool that can help me scroll less?

Comment: There should be a bar at the top of the editor tab that has (in 2015) dropdowns for the current project, full class name, and a third with methods present in the file.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the top-right side Drop Down list, just below the toolbar. That Drop Down contains a list of members of the class. Selecting an item directly jumps to its declaration.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do this.

1. The member dropdown in the editor window
2. (VS2010+) Ctrl-, (control-comma) will navigate to anything, using fuzzy search.